# How do I make discord bot have an emoji reaction after it sends its message in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want an emoji reaction AFTER the bot sends a message. The code below only does it after I type in the command. For example, these are some sample outputs:

Incorrect output:

User types in: rules
There is an emoji reaction
Bot message displays

Correct output:
User types in: rules
Bot message displays
There is an emoji reaction

````
client.on('message', (rules) => {
    const listen = rules.content; 
    if(listen === 'rules') {
        rules.channel.send('```**1. Be respectful**\r\n' +
        'You must respect all users, regardless of your liking towards them.\r\n\r\n' + 
        '**2. No Inappropriate Language**\r\n' +
        'The use of profanity should be kept to a minimum.\r\n\r\n' +
        '**3. No spamming**\r\n' + 
        'Don\'t send a lot of small messages right after each other. Do not disrupt chat by spamming.\r\n\r\n' + 
        '**4. No pornographic/adult/other NSFW material**\r\n' +
        'This is a community server and not meant to share this kind of material.\r\n\r\n' +
        '**5. No advertisements**\r\n' +
        'We do not tolerate any kind of advertisements, whether it be for other communities or streams.\r\n\r\n' + 
        '**6. No offensive names and profile pictures**\r\n' +
        'You will be asked to change your name or picture if the staff deems them inappropriate.\r\n\r\n' +
        '**7. Server Raiding**\r\n Raiding or mentions of raiding are not allowed.\r\n\r\n' +
        '**8. Direct & Indirect Threats**\r\n' +
        'Threats to other users of DDoS, Death, DoX, abuse,' + 
        'and other malicious threats are absolutely prohibited and disallowed.\r\n\r\n' +
        '**9. Follow the Discord Community Guidelines**\r\n' +
        'You can find them here: https://discordapp.com/guidelines \r\n\r\n' +
        '**10. Admins and higher roles have greater responsibility**\r\n' + 
        'The Admins and Mods will Mute/Kick/Ban per discretion.\r\n' + 
        'If you feel mistreated dm an Admin and we will resolve the issue.```\r\n' +
        '**Your presence in this server implies accepting these rules, including all further changes.\r\n' +
        'These changes might be done at any time without notice, it is your responsibility to check for them.**').then(rules.react(emojiArray[1]));
       
    }
})
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````js
client.on('message', (rules) => {
    const listen = rules.content; 
    if(listen === 'rules') {
        rules.channel.send('```**1. Be respectful**\r\n' +
        'You must respect all users, regardless of your liking towards them.\r\n\r\n' + 
        '**2. No Inappropriate Language**\r\n' +
        'The use of profanity should be kept to a minimum.\r\n\r\n' +
        '**3. No spamming**\r\n' + 
        'Don\'t send a lot of small messages right after each other. Do not disrupt chat by spamming.\r\n\r\n' + 
        '**4. No pornographic/adult/other NSFW material**\r\n' +
        'This is a community server and not meant to share this kind of material.\r\n\r\n' +
        '**5. No advertisements**\r\n' +
        'We do not tolerate any kind of advertisements, whether it be for other communities or streams.\r\n\r\n' + 
        '**6. No offensive names and profile pictures**\r\n' +
        'You will be asked to change your name or picture if the staff deems them inappropriate.\r\n\r\n' +
        '**7. Server Raiding**\r\n Raiding or mentions of raiding are not allowed.\r\n\r\n' +
        '**8. Direct & Indirect Threats**\r\n' +
        'Threats to other users of DDoS, Death, DoX, abuse,' + 
        'and other malicious threats are absolutely prohibited and disallowed.\r\n\r\n' +
        '**9. Follow the Discord Community Guidelines**\r\n' +
        'You can find them here: https://discordapp.com/guidelines \r\n\r\n' +
        '**10. Admins and higher roles have greater responsibility**\r\n' + 
        'The Admins and Mods will Mute/Kick/Ban per discretion.\r\n' + 
        'If you feel mistreated dm an Admin and we will resolve the issue.```\r\n' +
        '**Your presence in this server implies accepting these rules, including all further changes.\r\n' +
        'These changes might be done at any time without notice, it is your responsibility to check for them.**').then(r => r.react(emojiArray[1]));
       
    }
})
````

I am not sure if I understood your problem, but try this code above.